# How do I manage multiple repositories under a single repository in GitHub

Tags: git, github, xcode5

The reason is that, I want to create a single nice repository named "Stanford CS193P Homeworks" as a main repo (Just like a folder, which is nice to see in Github to present my code) under which i want to add all the homework 1, homework 2, etc.,

When i tried that i was unable to see the pushed repository,

You can see that the folder icon marked as grey in the image below,

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5irwj0xo7jpzw0f/Git.png

Each of those are individual git repos created in XCode 5.

Is it possible ? if so how do i enable it. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a single repo, with a directory intended for each homework assignment?

so when someone does a `clone`, they get this:

- root

  - hw1
  - hw2
  - hw3
  - etc...
  - README.md

Just copy the contents from each of your homework repos into a folder, and move them to a new repo.

Or, you could try using git submodules. I've never used them myself, but they seem to do what you're trying to do:

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial

Comment: If i do that, i guess i will not be able to collect all the commit changes that i made for that hw., ie., each hw folder themselves are git repos containing .git files. can i copy them as well ? to see all the commit made separately and the commit made for the root.

Comment: Well, if you keep your `.git` folder inside each homework folder, you can do a `git log` from inside that folder and still see all your commits.